# declare new type using js class

Tags: javascript, angular

I would create a new type that matches my data structure

Here's the format of data that i'm receiving

```
[{
    category1: [{
        fileName: "blabla"
    }, {
        fileDate: "DATE
    }, {
        fileURL: "http...."
    }]

}, {
    category2: [{
            fileName: "blabla2"
        },
        {
            fileDate: "DATE"
        },
        {
            fileURL: "http...."
        }
    ]

}]
```

I have created a class to define the model

```
export class CreditPoliciesDetails { 
    private _fileName : string ="" ;
    private _fileDate : string ="" ;
    private _fileSize : string ="" ;
    constructor() {
      this._fileDate="";
      this._fileName="";
      this._fileSize="";
    }
    get fileName() {
        return this._fileName;
    }
    get fileDate() {
        return this._fileDate;
    }
    get fileSize() {
        return this._fileSize;
    }
}
export class CreditPolicies {
    private _category : CreditPoliciesDetails;
    constructor () {}
    get category() {
        return this._category
    }
}
```

In my component file I import the model file then I define a new variable and console.log it

```
files : CreditPolicies;
ngOnInit() {
  console.log ("file details ", this.files)
}
```

I'm expecting to get type tree details but in my dev console I get undefined content : `file details  undefined`

How can I define correctly new type and print some default data ?

Comment: In your example `this.files` is undefined because you didn't assign any value to it.

Comment: I have initialised CreditPoliciesDetails items

Comment: Where? Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: in  `CreditPoliciesDetails` I initialize the three variables. How could I initialize `_category`

Comment: `files` isn't initialized anywhere and isn't related to CreditPoliciesDetails . _categories won't be an instance of CreditPoliciesDetails until you do _categories = new CreditPoliciesDetails . I guess your problem has something to do with JS/TS basic concepts rather than Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your constructor is pretty off there. If you want to create a new instance of your object, it should look more like this:

```
    private _fileName : string;
    private _fileDate : string;
    private _fileSize : string;
    constructor(fileDate: string, fileSize: string, fileSize: string) {
      this._fileDate = fileDate;
      this._fileName = fileName;
      this._fileSize = fileSize;
    }
```

That allows you to create a new instance of your object, kinda like this...

```
newObject: CreditPoliciesDetail = new CreditPoliciesDetail("10/10/2000", "mystuff.txt", "1923")
```

And then you could basically log it for fun with

console.log(newObject)

Generally speaking, you might want to pay https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html a visit and go through their tutorial. It's really nice to get the basic ideas of object orientated programming down.